# Elasticsearch large term dictionary

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents where several terms contains possibly thousands of possible values (which are distinct - across fields)

For example:

```html
{
  "term_1":["ssd2dfff","ds2fefd","zwdfdf",...],
  "term_2":["amm22d3ff","amm2daccfd","man2ewfsd",...]
 
}
```

I'm concerned that this will create a large dictionary and might cause a performance impact

Comment: What is the question here? It will be fine to store such documents to Elasticsearch, but executing such terms queries is a different story.

Comment: I would like to understand what are the impact of a very large language corpus.

 I'm interested in knowing which algorithm is used to lookup a term from an index / segment

Answer (score 0):

Didn't really get the question here. You're probably concerned that it might crash at any given point due to the thousands of possibilities. I don't know if that will be the case but this [article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-crash-elasticsearch) here may be useful for you to understand what may or may not work in Elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
I'm concerned that the term index will contain many terms (possibly larger than the Chinese language corpus) 

I'm interested in knowing which algorithm is used to lookup a term from an index / segment

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer points out, one big problem for you can be [mapping explosion](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-crash-elasticsearch#mapping-explosion). This happens when you have some pattern or random generated key in each record. It becomes worst if you have nested deep structures. The reason behind such explosion is that elasticsearch stores the mapping per type in the form of metadata where each key has its datatype stored. In my case, the records looked like below and created problems

```
{
  "term1": {
    "04980000002RxJ9": 0.5833333333333334, 
    "04980000002RxJB": 0.4166666666666667
  }, 
  "term2": {
    "04980000002RxJ9": "ARR", 
    "04980000002RxJA": "Services", 
    "04980000002RxJB": "Renewals"
  }
}
```

Your data however looks fine unless you don't have term1,term2,term3... going on as a series. You need not worry about the value in the dictionary because es won't care about the value if its an array.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? 
What is the computation penalty of searching a term as size of the term corpus ?